# How many shards is Facebook's user table partitioned across?

Tags: sharding

[Scaling services with Shard Manager](https://engineering.fb.com/2020/08/24/production-engineering/scaling-services-with-shard-manager/) on the Engineering at Meta site says:

> Shard Manager manages tens of millions of shards hosted on hundreds of thousands of servers across hundreds of applications in production.

[image: Sharded databases]

If the above is true, then suppose Facebook has 3 billion users and this table is partitioned across 10 million shards as the document suggests, then each table only contains 300 rows or users?

And so, whenever a query that requires returning an arbitrary list of users is made to the database, potentially 100s of thousands of servers go to work in parallel to fetch this list?

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3):

> across hundreds of applications in production

That's the key in the phrasing. Meta has hundreds of applications, not only Facebook. The `users` table in Facebook is not likely sharded that much (if at all).

Assembling the data from 10 million shards, in 300 row chunks, across the network, is going to have a lot of overhead that would be reduced by using less shards and larger chunks of data, e.g. millions of rows of data per shard.

---

> I added an image from the document. From that image, it clearly suggests that the user table is sharded.

This is a generalized image to demonstrate how their Shard Manager product works. It isn't conclusive, nor is this document, about exactly how Facebook's primary database is architected. However, yes there's a good chance the `users` table is sharded, but I doubt it's sharded by a huge amount. If there were over 100 shards for their primary tables that drive the main website application, I'd be surprised.

> If the user table only lives in one server, then how is this one server able to respond to millions of user request?

Millions of requests over what timeframe? Running a database instance on my laptop could handle 1 million requests in a day. That's a rhetorical question to demonstrate the question is really about concurrency. I'm not sure if Facebook gets 1 million *concurrent* user requests at any given instant, but if they did, some database systems can handle up to 50-100k concurrent connections (not exactly a one-to-one metric but close enough for discussion).

So, 10 shards would be able to handle that level of concurrency. It would depend on their primary database system (not sure if they still use MySQL) and I'm sure they'd want to give themselves some breathing room. So maybe they shard across 50 or so servers, idk. All very speculative but demonstrates how little sharding one actually needs.

> If a user makes a complex query to this table for an arbitrary list of users matching certain arbitrary filters

Good thing in a controlled application like Facebook, the end users don't have the ability to query the database arbitrarily like your example suggests. Any interaction from an end user on the Facebook website is going to ultimately go through a very specifically and well-defined query workflow that's been thoroughly tested and tuned.

I don't think there's any function in the Facebook website that would allow any end user to request 30 million records from the database in one go. And FWIW, on the kind of hardware that Facebook's servers use besides their other full stack optimization techniques, scanning 30 million rows from a table would probably only take their database around 1 second to do, roughly speaking.

As an aside, I've worked with tables that were multi-terabyte big, in the tens of billions of rows, on decently busy servers, with not a ton of hardware behind them, that used no sharding at all. Size of data at rest doesn't really matter for most things - as long as you control the access to the database.

> ...are you assuming that their data persist on RAM?

Not necessarily. NVMes are quite fast disk devices these days too. To load 30 million rows off disk, even if they were vanilla SSDs, would still be relatively quick. Again, it's speculation, but I wouldn't doubt Facebook's database servers are architected with some of the fastest storage devices.

I can load 1 million rows off disk in about 1 second on the database servers I currently maintain - which is nothing at the scale of Facebook. I wouldn't doubt Facebook is architected to be at least 25x faster than where I'm at.

Comment: I would assume facebook have sharding implemented across regions/countries and/or primary language.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong picture about the Facebook architecture.

When you google, then you find that Facebook may run up to 100'000 server. They may have 5 Billion users, for database sizing you need to count also the non-active users (how many user does your application have?).

This does not mean, they run 100'000 shards! Only a small share of this 100k servers are counted for shards. I guess most of them are used for replication in order to distribute the load. Facebook runs hundreds of applications (see [Meta Platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Platforms)), only a subset of these 100k servers hold what you see as a Facebook end-user.

In one article it says, Facebook generates 25 Terabytes of log data - daily! I would guess they need a few hundred servers only to manage their log data. They have servers for testing, you need servers to handle your accounting data and servers managing your customers (be aware, you are not the Facebook customer - you are the product being sold).

Personally I would guess, only a few hundred (replicated) servers are really used for the Facebook product - to serve 5 Billion users.